# Criar banco automaticamente com Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

Estou criando uma aplicação ASP.NET MVC com Code First. Este sistema é um software de gerenciamento de comércio. Gostaria de separar as informações de cada empresa, e não deixar tudo no mesmo banco. Pensamos inicialmente em deixar tudo no mesmo, mas pensamos na questão de performance. O banco cresceria muito, e demoraria para executar algumas coisas.

Pensei em criar o banco para o primeiro login daquela empresa, e em seguida, com o usuário logado ele poderia cadastrar os demais usuários. Ele seria tipo o "Master" da empresa. Então os outros usuário que ele cadastra-se iriam para um banco de `Logins` onde teria um campo que identificava a empresa daquele usuário, e acessava o banco da mesma. Eu só criaria o banco para o primeiro usuário da empresa.

Isto é possível?

Comment: Bem vindo aoSOpt. Oque você já tentou fazer?

Comment: Ainda não encontrei nada na internet. Consegui usar "Database.CreateIfNotExist()" no Contexto do meu banco para criar automaticamente ao rodar minha aplicação. Mas ele só cria o banco presente no meu Web.Config. Sei que para Desktop, é possível alterar o App.Config e me conectar a um banco diferente. Mas não sei como fazer isto no MVC, nem como criar bancos diferentes em tempo de execução.

Comment: Porque criar um banco, e não uma tabela? Não consegui enxergar a necessidade de ter que criar um banco pra cada usuario.

Comment: Este sistema é um software de gerenciamento de comércio, eu gostaria de separar as informações de cada empresa, e não deixar tudo no mesmo banco. Pensamos inicialmente em deixar tudo no mesmo, mas pensamos na questão de performance. O banco cresceria muito, e demoraria para executar algumas coisas. Como eu deveria fazer neste caso?

Comment: A abordagem que costumo utilizar é manter tudo no mesmo banco e criar uma entidade 'Empresa' onde você poderá cadastrar a matriz e as filiais. Pense a seguinte situação: uma filial pode ter mais de um usuário. Nesse caso você criaria realmente um banco para cada usuário?

Comment: Pensei em criar o banco para o primeiro login daquela empresa, e em seguida, com o usuário logado ele poderia cadastrar os demais usuários. Ele seria tipo o "Master" da empresa. Então os outros usuário que ele cadastra-se iriam para um banco de Logins onde teria um campo que identificava a empresa daquele usuário, e acessava o banco da mesma. Eu só criaria o banco para o primeiro usuário da empresa, entende?

Answer (score 2):

Isto só faz sentido se você tem um *deploy* de sistema por empresa. Portanto, teria uma base de empresa por sistema.

Se a ideia é servir um único sistema para várias empresas, sua ideia simplesmente não faz sentido. O volume alto de dados só afetaria a performance se você estruturar seu banco errado, o que é muito difícil dentro do Entity Framework porque ele te obriga a estruturar seu banco de dados da maneira correta.

De qualquer forma, a maneira correta de fazer isso que você quer é colocando esse usuário inicial em `Migrations/Configuration.cs`, método `Seed`. É por lá que se fazem inserções iniciais, como usuários de bancos e informações mínimas de outras entidades.

No mais, a estruturação do banco de dados deve levar em consideração que informações pertencentes a uma empresa precisam estar ligadas a uma entidade de empresa. Isto é modelagem elementar do banco e não é preciso explicar isso na resposta. Já para restrições de acesso por empresa [você encontra exemplos de como fazer aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2999+authorize).

Answer (score 2):

Usando dois dbContext seria simples, um para o cadastro de empresas (acessando um banco fixo) e outro para o banco especifico da empresa (banco dinâmico), o segundo poderia ler ou criar a ConnectionString baseado no cadastro de empresas.

O usuário Master seria cadastrado juntamente com as Empresas e seria adicionado ao banco especifico no método Seed.

Quando fosse feito o Login, se escolhe a empresa e isso direciona pra qual banco conectar